# Forward all user-input to Linux PTY in subprocess

Tags: c, linux, tty, pty

**Background**

I'm trying to build a wrapper for the shell. Running in a TTY, it spawns the regular shell in a child process via [`forkpty`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty). The intent is for *all* user input to be forwarded to the child process as-is, but to intercept the child's output and do some processing on it before copying it to the parent process' `stderr`. The user should be able to forget that the shell is wrapped at all, apart from the augmented output.

**Problem**

I can't figure out how to transparently forward the input. Here's the gist of my code currently (error checks and minor details omitted). It should compile with `gcc <filename> -pthread -lutil`:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 512
#define EOT "\x04"    // ASCII end-of-transmission (i.e. 'EOF').

void * tty_input_routine(void * arg);
void   tty_output_routine();
int    parent_term_fd;

volatile sig_atomic_t got_sigchld = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t got_sigwinch = 0;
// Listens for the child to exit, and causes the parent to exit.
void handle_sigchld(int sig) {
    got_sigchld = 1;
}
// Listens for the parent to be resized, and causes the child to be resized.
void handle_sigwinch(int sig) {
    got_sigwinch = 1;
}

void main() {
    /* Block SIGWINCH and SIGCHLD. They are later unblocked via pselect in the main loop. */
    sigset_t sigmask;
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGWINCH);    
    sigaddset(&sigmask, SIGCHLD);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmask, NULL);

    /* Establish signal handlers. */
    struct sigaction sig_action;
    sig_action.sa_flags = 0;
    sig_action.sa_handler = &handle_sigchld;
    sigemptyset(&sig_action.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sig_action, NULL);
    sig_action.sa_handler = &handle_sigwinch;
    sigaction(SIGWINCH, &sig_action, NULL);

    /* Get the initial terminal size. */
    struct winsize term_sz;
    ioctl(STDERR_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &term_sz);

    /* Turn off input echo in the child terminal since the parent should do that. */
    struct termios term_ios;
    tcgetattr(STDERR_FILENO, &term_ios);
    term_ios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);

    /* Do the fork. */
    pid_t child_pid = forkpty(&parent_term_fd, NULL, &term_ios, &term_sz);
    if (child_pid == 0) {
        /* This is the child process. Execute the shell. */
        char *const argv[] = { NULL };
        execvp("/bin/bash", argv);
    }
    /* This is the parent process.
     * Spawn a dedicated thread to forward input to the child PTY.
     * The main thread will be used to process the output. */
    pthread_t input_thread;
    pthread_create(&input_thread, NULL, &tty_input_routine, NULL);
    tty_output_routine(parent_term_fd);
}

void * tty_input_routine(void * arg) {
    struct termios tcattr;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tcattr);
    // cfmakeraw(&tcattr);                         // This doesn't seem to help.
    // tcattr.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;                  // Neither does this...
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tcattr);

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    while (true) {
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
        if (select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;  // A signal was caught; just try again.
            }
            // Otherwise, some error...
            puts("THIS IS UNEXPECTED");
            break;
        } else {
            ssize_t bytes = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (bytes > 0) {
                write(parent_term_fd, buf, (size_t)bytes);                               
            } else if (bytes == 0) {
                /* End of transmission? */
                write(parent_term_fd, EOT, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void tty_output_routine() {
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    sigset_t empty_sigmask;
    sigemptyset(&empty_sigmask);
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    while (true) {
        FD_SET(parent_term_fd, &fds);
        if (pselect(parent_term_fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL, &empty_sigmask) == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                /* A signal was caught. */
                if (got_sigwinch) {
                    got_sigwinch = 0;
                    struct winsize term_sz;
                    ioctl(STDERR_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &term_sz);
                    /* This sends SIGWINCH to the child. */
                    ioctl(parent_term_fd, TIOCSWINSZ, &term_sz);
                }
                if (got_sigchld) {
                    // This should run when the user does CTRL+D, but it doesn't...
                    puts("THIS IS THE PROPER EXIT");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                // Otherwise, some error...
                break;
            }
        } else {
            ssize_t bytes = read(parent_term_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
            // (Omitted) do some processing on the buffer.
            write(STDERR_FILENO, buf, (size_t)bytes);
        }
    
    }
}
```

- The idea is that when the user hits `CTRL+D`, the input routine will read an empty buffer, and send `EOT` to the child, which will exit, causing `SIGCHLD` to fire in the parent, which will also exit. However, `SIGCHLD` is never raised in the parent, even though `bash` definitely exits as shown by the fact that it prints `exit` to the screen. Confusingly, `SIGWINCH` appears to be handled just fine.
- Furthermore, the parent has trouble forwarding `CTRL+C` to the child. Even if I add another signal handler for `SIGTERM` and simply forward that signal to the child via `kill`, the shell itself exits, as opposed to whatever's running in the shell, as bash does normally. I'm not sure what to do differently here.
- I've tried [`cfmakeraw`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/cfmakeraw) and turning off canonical mode (`ICANON`) but this makes the program even more broken. Perhaps there are some other terminal attributes I'm missing?

It feels like I'm over-engineering this, since all I want to do is essentially trick the child process into accepting input as though it had no wrapping parent process. Do I really have to handle everything explicitly in the parent and manually forward user input and signals to the child? How can I do this in a way that the user can't tell that the shell is wrapped, apart from the augmented output?